# View button and routing in Angular

Tags: angular

I think I have a road that is not good. In the `Market` > `Value` section, when I click on the `Add` button, I do not see the `addition.component.html` page. I have the impression that the button does not work?!

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaAgT.png)

**value.component.html**

```
<div class="text-center">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="btnAjout()">Add</button>
</div>
```

**market-routing.module.ts**

```
export const MARKET_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/value',
  },

  {
    path: 'value',
    component: ValueComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'ajout',
    component: AjoutComponent,
  },

];
```

**market.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, MarketRoutingModule,  PipesModule,],
  declarations: [MarketComponent, ValueComponent],
})
export class MarketModule { }
```

**value.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AjoutComponent  
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class ValueModule { }
```

Here is an illustration on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-cxo2zx?file=src/app/views/dashboard/views/market/views/value/value.component.html).
User `toto` & Password `1234`.

Comment: What happens inside the `btnAjout` function? I think we need to know what's not working properly. The type of the button (as it's written in the question) should be "button" not "submit", but I doubt that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code, when you `navigateByUrl` to `ajout`, it replaces the entire route with `ajout`. On click of the button use the below routing.

```
 btnAjout(): void {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('dashboard/market/ajout');
  }
```

Here is a [Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-cxo2zx-lijpyu?file=src/app/views/dashboard/views/market/views/value/value.component.ts)